# OptimumX Delete Profiles - Windows XP machines

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, group-policy, user-profiles

Created a GPO to run a batch file on shutdown for domain XP computers - with the purpose of deleting old user profiles.

For this I am using an application called DeleteProfiles from OptimumX.

```
cd C:\
if exist "Program Files (x86)" GOTO Exit (Checks if XP or not)
if exist DeleteProfiles GOTO COMMAND

:CopyDeleteProfiles
md DeleteProfiles
copy /Y \\SomeShare\SomeFolder\DeleteProfiles\DeleteProfiles.exe 
C:\DeleteProfiles\

:COMMAND
pushd C:\DeleteProfiles\
start /Wait DeleteProfiles.exe /MIN:14 /Y
```

(/Min: # = Delete profiles older than # and /y removes yes or no prompts)

```
:Exit
End
```

It works alright, but, a CMD screen appears appears at shutdown, with the output of the program. How do I make it go away?

The real problem here is that users can close the program which causes the script to stop. If I can't make that go away, I would like at least to make the screen not close-able.

Comment: Have you tried the `start /b` option? "/B         Start application without creating a new window. "

Comment: Wow, thanks! that was it! should have looked up start /? haha

Comment: Great. I shall add an answer, which you will able to accept.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I make it go away?

You can use `start` with the `/b` option:

```
start /b /Wait DeleteProfiles.exe /MIN:14 /Y
```

> `/B` - Start application without creating a new window. In this case ^C will be ignored - leaving ^Break as the only way to interrupt the application.

Source - [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).